# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY when trying to delete OppotunityLineItemSchedule

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm stuck on this error and can't figure out where is the problem:

I have a trigger on Opportunity object which would look at another Opportunities OpportunityLineItems and see if the OppotunityLineItemSchedule is older then original OpportunityLineItem start date and delete all the schedules that are.
Here is a trigger:

```
trigger CreateOpportunityProductSchedules on Opportunity (after update) {

    List <Id> oppoIds = new List <Id>();
    List <Id> contrIds = new List<Id>();
    List <Id> origOppoIds = new List <Id>();
    List <OpportunityLineItem> oli = new List <OpportunityLineItem>();
    List <OpportunityLineItem> origOli = new List <OpportunityLineItem>();
    List <Contract> contracts = new List <Contract>();
    List <opportunityLineItemSchedule> oliSchedule = new List <opportunityLineItemSchedule>();

    for (Opportunity oppo : Trigger.new){
        oppoIds.add(oppo.Id);
        contrIds.add(oppo.SBQQ__AmendedContract__c);
    }

    if (contrIds != null){
        contracts = [SELECT Id, SBQQ__Opportunity__c FROM Contract WHERE Id = :contrIds];
    }
    for (Contract con : contracts){
        origOppoIds.add(con.SBQQ__Opportunity__c);
    }
    if (oppoIds != null){
        oli = [SELECT Id, Type_Name__c, ListPrice, SBQQ__SubscriptionType__c, Effective_Start_Date__c, Effective_End_Date__c, TotalPrice, OpportunityId, Product2Id, Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = :oppoIds];
    }
    if (origOppoIds != null){
        origOli = [SELECT Id, TotalPrice, Product2Id, Quantity, Type_Name__c, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = :origOppoIds];
    }
    if (origOli != null){
        oliSchedule = [SELECT Id, ScheduleDate FROM opportunityLineItemSchedule WHERE OpportunityLineItemId = :origOli];
    }

    for (Opportunity oppo : Trigger.new){
        for (OpportunityLineItem olil : oli){
            if (olil.OpportunityId == oppo.Id && olil.Quantity < 0){
                for (OpportunityLineItem oolil : origOli){
                    List <opportunityLineItemSchedule> schedulesToDelete = new List <opportunityLineItemSchedule>();
                    if (oolil.Product2Id == olil.Product2Id && oolil.Quantity + olil.Quantity == 0){
                        for (opportunityLineItemSchedule olisch : oliSchedule){
                            if (olisch.ScheduleDate >= olil.Effective_Start_Date__c){
                                if (!schedulesToDelete.contains(olisch)){
                                    schedulesToDelete.add(olisch);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    delete schedulesToDelete;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trigger works fine as long as there is one OpportunityLineItem on Opportunity that enters the trigger when there are more then one I get this error:

> caused by: System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row
>   0 with id 00o0C000000SK5bQAG; first error:
>   INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

I would much appreciate any help or clues.

Thanks

Comment: I have only ever seen this sort of thing with sharing rule issues - one of the keys may be identifying an object for which the user has no access?

Comment: I don't think it's a permission issue as I always test it with same object and if I have just one opportunity line item it works fine

Comment: The first thing you should consider is removing the delete DML statement from inside the for Loop. This is bad design which will ultimately result in your code hitting governor limits.

Comment: I note that you have 4 levels of loop in this code. This, too, is bad design. Apex loops are really CPU greedy, so you can expect to hit CPU limits real quick with any moderately large number of values to iterate at each level. Instead consider a few sequential loops used to set up maps and the like. For example, you could set up a map of opportunity ID to list of line items for that opportunity. You could also simply only include line items in your query that have a negative quantity.